# Windows Powershell - Format gci output

Tags: powershell

I need to output the response from GCI via Powershell to a specific format.

Previously, we used to use a MAC to output the contents of a directory. It appeared in the following format:

> 8.0K  ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/Clip/A02/A02M01.xml
> 7.3G    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/Clip/A02/A02.mxf
> 7.3G    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/Clip/A02
> 37G    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/Clip
> 4.0K    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/General
> 4.0K    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ/MEDIAPRO.xml
> 37G    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ
> 4.0K    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ/A024CKKQ.mhl
> 37G    ./z_TEST/TAPE 01/DAY_1/01/A024CKKQ

Using the following command in Windows Powershell:

```
gci -rec -file|%{"$($_.Fullname) $($_.Length)"} >AAA.txt
```

I am able to output the following:

> C:\z_TEST\TAPE 01\DAY_1\01\A024CKKQ\A024CKKQ\Clip\A02\A02M01.xml 8000
> C:\z_TEST\TAPE 01\DAY_1\01\A024CKKQ\A024CKKQ\Clip\A02\A02.mxf 7838311302
> C:\z_TEST\TAPE 01\DAY_1\01\A024CKKQ\A024CKKQ.mhl 4000
> C:\z_TEST\TAPE 01\DAY_1\01\A024CKKQ\A024CKKQ\MEDIAPRO.xml 4000

You will notice the slight differences. Mostly the file sizes and the ommitance of directories on the PowerShell output.

Is there a way I can format the output or am I best to create some code which transforms the text?

Thank you

Comment: If you specify the file switch you're specifically omitting the directories

Comment: Thank you. Removing the -file switch does indeed include the directories. Unfortunately these appear with a "1" file size. I assume there is no way to correctly format the file size back to the example at the top of my post?

Comment: So you are looking for the same format as in Mac? That would need some string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
$targetfolder='C:\temp'
# Get folder list    
$FileFolderList = Get-ChildItem -Force $targetfolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % {
    $len = 0
    # Process sizes
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $_.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { $len += $_.length }
    $foldername = $_.fullname
    # Format for size in Mb, you could put in a Switch statement if you want Gb/Kb/Tb according to size
    $foldersize= '{0:N2}' -f ($len / 1Mb)
    # Output as custom object
    [pscustomobject] @{Path=$foldername;SizeMb=$foldersize}
}
$FileFolderList # You can pipe this to a csv (Export-Csv)or text file
```